# How do I count the distinct fields from a given csv/psv hybrid text file?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, rdd

I believe Python is the best choice but I can be wrong.

Below is a sample from a data source in text format in Linux:

```
TUI,39832020:09:01,10.56| TUI,39832020:10:53,11.23| TUI,39832020:15:40,23.20
DIAN,39832020:09:04,11.56| TUI,39832020:11:45,11.23| DIAN,39832020:12:30,23.20| SLD,39832020:11:45,11.22
```

The size is unknown, let's presume a million rows.

Each line contains three or more sets delimited by `|`, and each set has fields separated by `,`.

The first field in each set is the product ID. For example, on the sample above, `TUI`, `DIAN`, and `SLD` are products ID.

I need to find out how many types of products I have on file. For example, the first line contains 1: `TUI`, the second line contains 3: `DIAN`, `TUI`, and `SLD`.

In total, on those two lines, we can see there are three unique products.

Can anyone help?

Thank you very much. Any enlightening is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I prefer a solution based in  Python with Spark, i.e. pySpark.

I'm also looking for statistics like:

- total amount of each product;
- all records for a given time (the second field in each set, like `39832020:09:01`);
- minimum and maximum price for each product.

**UPDATE 2**

Thank you all for the code, I really appreciate. I wonder if anyone can write the data into a RDD and/or dataframe. I know that in SparkSQL it is very simple to obtain those statistics.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I guess I figured out all you said and have updated my answer with snippets for each task. Check it out and let me know if you need something else.

Comment: What is `39832020` in `39832020:09:01`? The second part I can infer it is the time but I couldn't figure the first half out.

Comment: What did you try already? Please, check ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips on those articles. Even though I've provided you an alternative, you need to show us what you did by yourself and then we can help you go further. We can't code the solution for you. SO is not for that kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Accdias answer: Use a dictionary, read your file in line by line, split the data by `|` then by `,` and total up the counts in your dictionary.

```
myFile="lines_to_read.txt"
productCounts = dict()

with open(myFile, 'r') as linesToRead:
    for thisLine in linesToRead:
        for myItem in thisLine.split("|"):
            productCode=myItem.split(",")
            productCode=productCode[0].strip()
            if productCode in productCounts:
                productCounts[productCode]+=1
            else:
                productCounts[productCode]=1

print(productCounts)
```

**** Update ****
Dataframe use with Pandas so that we can query stats on the data afterwords:

```
import pandas as pd

myFile="lines_to_read.txt"
myData = pd.DataFrame (columns=['prodID', 'timeStamp', 'prodPrice'])

with open(myFile, 'r') as linesToRead:
    for thisLine in linesToRead:
        for myItem in thisLine.split("|"):
            thisItem=myItem.strip('\n, " "').split(",")
            myData = myData.append({'prodID':thisItem[0],'timeStamp':thisItem[1],'prodPrice':thisItem[2]}, ignore_index=True)

print(myData)   # Full Table
print(myData.groupby('prodID').agg({'prodID':'count'}))  # Total of prodID's
print(myData.loc[myData['timeStamp'] == '39832020:11:45']) # all lines where time = 39832020:11:45
print(myData.groupby('prodID').agg({'prodPrice':['min', 'max']})) # min/max prices
```

Comment: Thank you Brian, is it possible to provide a RDD/Dataframe solution?

Comment: @mdivk Challenge accepted, answer updated.  Note this code is very striped down and has little or no error handling and is based off a tiny data set.

Comment: Thank you Brian, the reason I asked for DataFrame solution is I like to do ad-hoc query by registering the df as TempTable, I understand there are API in the pandas data frame to do that, however, I personally think TempTable is the easiest way to get that done quickly